# Run Executable jar file from java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jar

I want to run executable jar located in `/WEB-INF/lib` from my  java `servlet` and get the output.
tried :

```
Process procesSH;
BuffererdReader br = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/WEB-INF/lib/jarName.jar", "-jar", "parma01 parma02");
procesSH = pb.start(); // start pb
br = BuffererdReader(new InputStreamReader(procesSH.getInputStream()));
system.out.println(br.readLine()); // read just one line for now
```

The error I get is:

```
CreateProcess error = 2, system cannot find file specified.
```

The file is located under `/WEB-INF/lib` , if there is more info needed I will post it.

Thanks.

Comment: I export to '.ear' file and place it on Webshpere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/WEB-INF/lib/jarName.jar` obviously did not work, here is a way to obtain an absolute path to the jar via the `ServletContext`:

```
ServletContext context = ...
String jarpath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/lib/jarName.jar");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(jarpath, "-jar", "parma01 parma02");
```

Comment: Are you sure that the order is (jarPth,"-jar","parma01 parma02")?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I just copied that from your question.